# scaling div and make content not scale

Tags: css, scale

I've been trying to scale a div, but not the content for a long time now. I've looked at examples and saw ways it was supposed to work, but it seems like it might be impossible to make it work :( the problem is that the image inside the div becomes blurry on scale. (on hover.)

Here's my codepen link
http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/5cf90a3d7b3e2f592ebcb0ebb9d07bf9

```
.child
  position: absolute
  height: 450px
  width: 20%
  background-color: #1f2733
  border-radius: 0 
  background-position: 50% 50%
  background-size: cover
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
  top: 0
  overflow: hidden
  z-index: 0
  transition: all 0.05s ease-in-out
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0)

  &:hover
    transform: scale(1.03)
    z-index: 2
    border-radius: 4px
    cursor: pointer
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    .child__content  
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(.947)
```

thank you for any help

Comment: What do you want to scale, and what do you want not to scale?

Comment: And your code pen does not load

Comment: Hey, i think using this
`image-rendering: optimizeSpeed
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast
  image-rendering: optimize-contrast
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor`  
worked. 

I guess you couldn't access the pen because it was private. it should work now

http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/5cf90a3d7b3e2f592ebcb0ebb9d07bf9